# How to generate plain (static) HTML from ERB that can be used in non-rails apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Say I have an ERB file that displays custom HTML depending on the user. But I also want to upload each user's custom HTML output to an S3 Bucket as **plain (static) HTML** so it can be used by **non-rails** applications. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, you should look into the [rails capture helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-capture)

You could wrap your `layouts/application.html.erb` template with the `capture` method. This will put the static HTML rendered by ERB  into an variable. For example:

```
<% @page = capture do %>
  <html>Your HTML Page</html>
<% end %>
```

You will then need to create a method with your Amazon S3 credentials to push this data to your bucket.